# Can a UDF access a parameter or a defined value declared in the calling Pig script?

Tags: apache-pig, user-defined-functions

I am simply trying in any way that is possible to modify the functionality of a UDF. For example, say I had a UDF which filtered based on percentile -- I would like be able to do something in the Pig script like "define percentile 90" and have the UDF be able to access this number.

That's pretty much it.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, I just found this quick here:

https://www.inkling.com/read/programming-pig-alan-gates-1st/chapter-6/controlling-execution

You use "set" and the value set is available within JobConf. More info about JobConf found here:

https://www.inkling.com/read/programming-pig-alan-gates-1st/chapter-10/writing-an-evaluation-function#b0917dc6a9bd21005971e7b7198e1b49

The alternative of using define to pass an argument to the constructor is also discussed in stackoverflow and this Inkling book but it seems like JobConf will be a good approach -- I suspect using define has limitations.